# Refactoring packages to match UI hierarchy

Tags: android, refactoring

Currently my app is mainly a bunch of Java files in the .app package. I'm simulating a hierarchy by giving the classes odd names.

```
My_0_MainActivity.java
My_0_CenterLayout.java
My_1_1_0_CenterPageOptionsFragment.java
My_1_1_1_CenterPageGridFragment.java
My_1_1_CenterPagerFragment.java
My_1_2_CenterSettingsFragment.java
My_2_DrawerLeftBaseFragment.java
My_3_0_DrawerRightDatePickerFragment.java
My_3_1_DrawerRightOptionsFragment.java
My_3_DrawerRightBaseFragment.java
...
```

should reflect

```
MainActivity.java
 +-CenterFragment.java
 |  +-CenterPagerFragment.java
 |  |  +-CenterPageOptionsFragment.java
 |  |  +-CenterPageGridFragment.java
 |  +-CenterSettingsFragment.java
 +-DrawerLeftBaseFragment.java
 +-DrawerRightBaseFragment.java
   +-DrawerRightDatePickerFragment.java
   +-DrawerRightOptionsFragment.java
```

so I thought I would create sub-packages like

```
 .app.MainActivity.java
 .app.center.BaseFragment.java
 .app.center.pager.MainFragment.java
 .app.center.pager.page.OptionsFragment.java
 .app.center.pager.page.GridFragment.java
 .app.center.settings.MainFragment.java
 .app.drawer.left.MainFragment.java
 .app.drawer.right.MainFragment.java
 .app.drawer.right.page.DatePickerFragment.java
 .app.drawer.right.page.OptionsFragment.java
```

While starting to refactor, I got the message

`Error:(260, 50) error: m_strTitle is not public in My_0_ApplicationState.TopicObject; cannot be accessed from outside package`

This is because `My_0_ApplicationState`, which is in the .app package contains a class named TopicObject which has a private member called m_strTitle which I'm accessing from this new package `center.pager.MainFragment`, which used to be a sibling to `My_0_ApplicationState` in the .app package, named `My_1_1_CenterPagerFragment`. Previously, while they where all in the same package, this was not an error.

Changing the member of TopicObject to public solves this issue, but this lead me to think if I may be making this refactoring wrong.

Is it good to do this refactoring, or should I use another approach? Will this refactoring leave my code cleaner, or introduce a method of doing things that should not be done that way?

Answer (score 0):

Having proper packages in code makes it much cleaner and easier to read later. Only thing you should take care what to expose to outside world use proper access modifiers or provide alternate way to access the data.

Comment: So you mean that changing to this layout is a sensible thing to do? When looking at the ioshed-GoogleI/O app, it has tons of files in the ui folder without any hierarchy.

Comment: I mean, I'm getting to a point where one package contains only one fragment and nothing else, is this ok?

Comment: One package having one fragment is kinda too much hierarchy. Usually what I follow is all fragment goes in one frgament package, all util goes in utils package. This way its much easier to manage 100's of source files.